# how to include stored procedures with Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator version 2.14.3

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, poco

I am using the Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator version 2.14.3 and I would like to include only stored procedures with name starts "usp_CMT_update*" in Apps schema.  I used default settings for stored proocedure in the .tt file but only some of them were generated.  I also tried regex pattern but still didn't get the stored proc generated. Please help.  Thanks.

```
// Stored Procedures *****************************************************
// Use the following regex filters to include or exclude stored procedures
StoredProcedureFilterExclude = null;
StoredProcedureFilterInclude = null;
```

//StoredProcedureFilterInclude = New regex("^usp_cmt*");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that all the stored procedures are created in the DataContext class.  If the stored procedure return records, there will be an object property with stored procedure name suffixed with ReturnModel.