# Calling Stored Procedures using Reverse POCO Generator

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I have a reverse POCO Generator bring models across from my database. I've added a stored procedure but I can't find it anywhere and don't know how to call it using Entity Framework.

I have `IncludeStoredProcedures = true;` and `IncludeTableValuedFunctions = true;`  set in the .tt config file. There are no errors or warnings in the console after hitting save and the Stored Procedure config is below:

```
// Stored Procedures ******************************************************************************************************************
    // Use the following regex filters to include or exclude stored procedures
    StoredProcedureFilterExclude = null;
    StoredProcedureFilterInclude = null;

    // Filtering of stored procedures using a function. This can be used in conjunction with the Regex's above.
    // Regex are used first to filter the list down, then this function is run last.
    // Return true to include the stored procedure, return false to exclude it.
    StoredProcedureFilter = (StoredProcedure sp) =>
    {
        // Example: Exclude any stored procedure in dbo schema with "order" in its name.
        //if(sp.Schema.Equals("dbo", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && sp.NameHumanCase.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("order"))
        //    return false;

        return true;
    };
```

My understanding from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639876/how-to-include-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-reverse-poco-generator-ve) is that because my Stored Procedure is not returning any data, but completing an insert, it won't be transferred with POCO. Is that right? If so is there any way round this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and for me, I solve this problem with inserting `SET FMTONLY OFF` at top of stored procedure (just after `SET NOCOUNT ON`)